# how to get the number of ticks for a turtle takes to go to a green patch?

Tags: netlogo

There is a one red patch and `10` turtles moving randomly.

When a turtle comes to the `red` patch, it becomes `green`.

I want to run the model 100 times and get the number of ticks (it takes for the first patch color change) for all 100 runs into an excel sheet.

```
to setup
  clear-all      ; clear everything when we click setup
  setup-patches
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  ask n-of humans patches [set pcolor green]
end

to setup-turtles
  create-turtles Mosquitos
  ask turtles [
    set size 1
    set shape "bug"
    set color yellow
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
     ]
    ask turtles
     [
      ifelse coin-flip?
          [ifelse coin-flip? [set heading 0][set heading 90]]
          [ifelse coin-flip? [set heading 180][set heading 270]]
    ]

end

to go
  ask turtles
    [
       ifelse coin-flip?
          [ifelse coin-flip? [set heading 0][set heading 90]]
          [ifelse coin-flip? [set heading 180][set heading 270]]
       forward 1
        if pcolor = green
          [
            set pcolor red
          show ticks
          ]
    ]
        tick
end

to-report coin-flip?
  report random 2 = 0
end
```

Comment: Since it only turns green once, this question is a bit confusing. Do you want it to output the `ticks` instead of `show` once, or are you intending to run the simulation many times and want all the runs to output to the same file?

Comment: Not related to your question: Your coin-flip? procedure could be simplified. Instead of reporting whether random 0 or 1 is 0, you can simply say `report one-of [true false]` since `one-of` selects uniform randomly between the choices.

Comment: coinflip make turtles move up,down,left,right randomly each tick.When press setup,turtles are placed randomly.press go &turtles start moving randomly forever. When a turtle comes to the green patch,it turns red and the tick time it became red is shown on commandcenter.(ex 45).After the patch becomes red, turtles are moving but if they come to the already red patch a tick time will not be shown(i.e the first time  turtle comes to the patch tick time is shown on command center). i want run procedure 100 times and get those 100 tick times and get them to a excel.

Answer (score 0):

BehaviorSpace automatically keeps track of the steps. All you need to do is set up a BehaviorSpace experiment that stops the simulation wh`en the patch turns green.

You need to tell BehaviorSpace to stop when a patch turns green. So `any? patches with [pcolor = green]` as the stop condition in the experiment. You don't need anything in the box "Measure runs using these reporters" box as the step is sent to the file, so just leave it as `count turtles`. Also uncheck the box so that it only reports at the end of the run. Use the table form of BehaviorSpace output.

Comment: Sir. Thanks a lot for helping me. Btw I want the tick time a turtle meets the colored patch first, Say 123. Press setup and go.Then 345.Press setup and go.Then 23. Likewise it can be any tick time. No restriction. I want to do it 100 times and get 100 corresponding tick times to excel.tick time can be greater than 100 .Can you make the corrections in the code i made and send me? (i want to make a code so that by pressing only one button I get 100 different tick values in excel. I thought behavior space is needed) Thanks

Comment: If all you want to do is have it stop the first time it hits a green patch, then yes, you want BehaviorSpace. BehaviorSpace automatically creates an Excel file so it's unclear what you need help with.

Comment: Sir.The first time a turtle hits a green patch, say tick 45. I want to do this 100 times and get the average time it takes to hit the patch. What should I write in the box "Measure runs using these reporters"? I cannot write count ticks . Btw i can write in the repetitions box "100". "BehaviorSpace automatically creates an Excel file"?? This doesn't work for me. I think my question is clear now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. But it is still not working. Sir. can you do the correction(Change show ticks to stop) in my code and after filling the behaviourSpace box and tell me whether you get 100 random tick times in excel. I even can't get them to an excel sheet. Thank You!

Comment: No changes are needed in the code. You need to set up the BehaviorSpace experiment to stop when there's a green patch. See edit. If you can't make it work, show us the BehaviorSpace dialogue box.

Comment: Thank You very much sir. It is now working. Thanks aloooot.